# type regular expression in share latex

Tags: regex, latex

I am writing a report on latex. In report, I have to mention a regular expression that I have created as a part of development project but I am not able to write it on latex. 
For example when I am trying to enter below expression,I  am getting error, I understand that "\" has a special meaning but in my case I want to write exact as below .

[A-Z]+\w

Kindly help me, I tried looking everywhere but did not get any final solution.

Comment: offsite canonical https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex

Comment: \textbackslash worked in this case